# Trouble running maven-grails test cases

Tags: grails, maven

I'm using Maven 3.0.3, Grails 1.2.1.  I mavenized my Grails project, however, although I've created integration and unit tests, maven does not run them.  Granted the tests are in the Grails directory structure (PROJECT_HOME/test/unit and PROJECT_HOME/test/integration) as opposed to the Maven directory structure, I thought the maven-grails plugin would allow this but no tests get run.  Below is the complete output.  Any ideas how to make "maven test" run my Grails' test cases?

Thanks, - Dave

```
davea-mbp2:socialmediaproxy davea$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building socialmediaproxy 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:1.2.1:validate (default) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:1.2.1:init (default) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:1.2.1:config-directories (default) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/socialmediaproxy/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:1.2.1:maven-compile (default) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] Using Grails 1.2.1
Running pre-compiled script
Environment set to development
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/socialmediaproxy/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/socialmediaproxy/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:1.2.1:maven-test (default) @ socialmediaproxy ---
[INFO] Using Grails 1.2.1
Running pre-compiled script
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.194s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 05 14:23:44 CDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/110M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:1.2.1:maven-test (default) on project socialmediaproxy: Unable to start Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Did you ever get a solution for this? I am stuck at the same point and I don't know how to proceed on this :(

Answer (score 0):

To use the  maven-grails plugin for the tests you have to call it explicitly try `mvn grails:test-app`

You can display all possible commands for this plugin via  `mvn grails:help`